# Help needed on installation of Ubuntu server (precise pagolin)

Tags: 12.04

When the installation of the base system of Ubuntu server has reached 80%, it tells me to insert a disc called "Ubuntu server 12.04.4 LTS Precise Pangolin-Release i386 (20140204)" in `/media/ cdrom/`

What should i do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Since English is the language of this site, please post your questions in English next time.

Comment: are you installing from cdrom or liveusb, or sth. else ?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem using a burned DVD.
Using that one DVD I was able to install on one machine **perfectly** but installation on a second machine crapped out at 80% like the above. I doubled checked the md5sum, CD integrity, and even burned another DVD and still no dice.

To solve I burned on to a CD instead and installed perfectly on the second machine...go figure!